# Choosing AngularJS or Angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I have been learning SPA using webAPI and AngularJS of late. Today I came across that AngularJS 2 has been released and it has advantages over AngularJS.

Now I am confused if I should continue learning SPA using AngularJS or should I leave it aside and concentrate on SPA using AngularJS 2, ASP.NET 5 and TypeScript.
Please guide me which is better option. Thanks in advance

Comment: " AngularJS 2 has been released" - it's still in beta, and it will be for some time...

Comment: This may be a better question for chat.stackoverflow.com. "Opinion based questions" are not generally for this portion of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2 is still in beta, so if you want a more stable version use angular js. I think that as you mentioned you are learning I would recommend going with angularjs since you will find a big community and lots of documentation online.

Answer (score 1):

So far I know AngularJS 2 is in its beta (but I think it's now usable, at least for learning), but if you don't have a production application in 1.x or you won't maintain 1.x code, I'd start learning 2.0, since at the end, you'd be using 2.0 (if you'd stick to NG).